# not as adjective as to change comparative adjective

Tags: comparison

> This computer holds less information than that.

If I change this sentence into "not as adjective as",

> That computer does not hold as little information as this.

Is this sentence grammatical or not?

Answer (score 1):

> 2. That computer does not hold as little information as this.

This is an acceptable paraphrase of

> 1. This computer holds less information than that.

But although both sentences express the same relative capacities of the two computers, they do not mean the same thing.

- Sentence 1 provides information about **this** computer and answers the question *How **much** information does this computer hold?*
- Sentence 2 provides information about **that** computer and answers the question *How **little** information does that computer hold?*.

If what you are interested in the relative capacities of the two computers, sentence 2 is a very odd and indirect way of expressing yourself. Capacity is ordinarily a positive value, an "asset", ranked on a rising, positive scale—how **much**? But sentence 2 implies that you regard capacity as a negative value, a "debt"—the computer with the least capacity is for the purposes of your inquiry more valuable or interesting than computers with a greater capacity.